# Как узнать текущую таксономию?

Tags: wordpress

Как комбинировать 2 таксономии?

1. такс - страна
2. такс - тур-тип

Как для ссылки комбинировать url адрес, чтобы получить: `country/russia/tour-type/nature`?

```html
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Taxonomy-Country.
 *
 * @package toursgid
 */
 get_header(); ?>
 
<?php
global $wp_query;
 
$myquery = new WP_Query(
 array_merge(
  array(
  'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'post_type' => 'travels',
     'tour-type'    => 'spa'
  ), // это параметр который добавили мы
  $wp_query->query // это массив базового запроса текущей страницы
 )
);
  

if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : $myquery->the_post(); ?>



 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>


<?php endwhile; ?>
 
<a  href="http://toursgid.ru/?country=russia&tour-type=spa" class="mob_bottom">
        СПА (текущес страны)
</a>

<?php
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 
<?php
global $wp_query;
$query = new WP_Query(
 array_merge(
  array(
  'posts_per_page' => 4,
  'post_type' => 'travels',
     'tour-type'    => 'nature'
  ), // это параметр который добавили мы
  $wp_query->query // это массив базового запроса текущей страницы
 )
);
  

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>



 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a>


<?php endwhile;
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
<a  href="http://toursgid.ru/?country=russia&tour-type=nature" class="mob_bottom">
        Природа (текущес страны)
</a>
 
<?php
get_footer();
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно, приведите конкретный пример, чего вы хотите, и желаемый результат.

Comment: Привел посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Ну обычно это так пишут site.ru/страница/?country=russia&tour-type=nature

Comment: я так и делаю но мне надо чтобы country=(текущая страна), как так реализовать ?

Comment: Загадками говорите. Что такое "текущая страна"? Приведите код, чтобы было понятно, что вы сделали и что не получается.

Comment: Добавил код посмотрите пожалуйста 
там где ссылка a=href нужно добавить ссылку чтобы запомнила текущую страну

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось из комментариев, вам надо всего лишь узнать название текущей таксономии и вставить в ссылку.

Попробуйте вместо

```
<a  href="http://toursgid.ru/?country=russia&tour-type=nature" class="mob_bottom">
    Природа (текущес страны)
</a>
```

Сделать так

```
<a  href="http://toursgid.ru/?country=<?php echo get_query_var('taxonomy'); ?>&tour-type=nature" class="mob_bottom">
    Природа (текущей страны)
</a>
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку 404

Comment: Спасибо большое  получилось очень благодарен.

Comment: Если ответ полезен, его стоит отметить как принятый галочкой внизу. Это поможет ориентироваться пользователям, которые ищут ответ на подобный вопрос.

Comment: Не могу найти кроме этих кнопок (поделиться править удалить тревога)

Comment: Слева от ответа, где большие цифры. Нажмете на галку, станет зеленой. http://take.ms/BrGLP

Comment: Я бы советовал сменить заголовок. Например: "Как узнать текущую таксономию?", потому что сейчас заголовок вообще не отображает суть вопроса.

Comment: ok )))))))))))))))))

Comment: @WP_LOAD это имеет смысл, потому что здесь не просто форум, и вообще не форум, а база знаний. С правильным заголовком выше вероятность того, что вопрос и ответ смогут найти.